# How to dynamically make a combobox multiselect/singleselect in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I am using **Boxselect** extended from combo box in **ExtJs 4.1**. Based on some condition i need to make the selection single or multi.

here is my code

```
bool result;
result = getData();
if(result)
{
  Ext.getCmp("combo1").multiSelect =true
}
```

This does not change the combobox to multiselect .any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to force the recreation of the picker when the `multiSelect` option change. For that, you need to delete the property `picker` of your combo:

```
 combo.multiSelect = true;
 delete combo.picker;
```

Complete example:

```
Ext.widget('panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    layout: {type: 'vbox', align: 'center'},
    margin: 10,
    defaults: {width: 200, margin: 5},
    items: [{
        xtype: 'combo',
        store: ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz']
    },{
        xtype: 'displayfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Multiselect is',
        value: "OFF"
    },{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: "Toggle multiselect",
        handler: function() {
            var panel = this.up(),
                combo = panel.down('combo'),
                outField = panel.down('displayfield'),
                newValue = !combo.multiSelect;
            combo.multiSelect = newValue;
            // force recreation of picker
            delete combo.picker;
            outField.setValue(newValue ? "ON" : "OFF");
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with the Ext.apply method.

```
combo = Ext.getCmp.....  
Ext.apply(combo, {multiSelect: true});
```

Comment: -1, apply() will have exactly the same effect as the code in the question.